# Ignite Cluster is not able to start after setting loadBalancingSpi

Tags: ignite, gridgain

After configuring the RR Load Balancing when I start the Ignite Cluster it is failing with the below error:

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to initialize SPI context.
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.onKernalStart(GridManagerAdapter.java:643)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1124)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2038)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1730)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1158)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1076)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:962)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:861)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:731)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:700)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:348)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:301)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Required event types are disabled: TASK_FAILED, TASK_FINISHED, JOB_MAPPED
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.loadbalancing.roundrobin.RoundRobinLoadBalancingSpi.onContextInitialized0(RoundRobinLoadBalancingSpi.java:279)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiAdapter.onContextInitialized(IgniteSpiAdapter.java:222)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.onKernalStart(GridManagerAdapter.java:368)
        ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says in the error message:

> Required event types are disabled: TASK_FAILED, TASK_FINISHED, JOB_MAPPED

You can enable the events by [following the documentation](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/events), but, basically, add something like the following to your configuration file:

```
<!-- Enable cache events. -->
<property name="includeEventTypes">
    <list>
        <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED"/>
        <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED"/>
        <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_JOB_MAPPED"/>
    </list>
</property>
```

Comment: After adding those properties when I started the Ignite Cluster it is failing with the error "The prefix "util" for element "util:constant" is not bound"

Comment: @sandipbhowmik You should import util namespace as follows:
```<beans ...
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="        ...
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">```